# How to save and load Objects to and from a file

Tags: java, list, file, rss, feed

I'm gonna be honest I am panicking. I am doing an exam in a Java course and I have been stuck for some time now.

I have to implement a RSS Feader and I am currently doing methods to save and load subscribed feeds. I thought I got the saveSubscribedFeeds method right because it passes the JUnit Test but I am starting to think I have some kind of error in there so that the loadSubscribeFeeds method cannot work properly.

Here is the saveSubscribedFeeds method:

```
public void saveSubscribedFeeds(List<Feed> feeds, File feedsFile) {
    
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
           writer = new FileWriter(feedsFile); 
        for(Feed f: feeds) {
            writer.write(f + System.lineSeparator());
        }
        
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
    }
    
}
```

For the loadSubscribedFeed method I already tried a Scanner, BufferedReader and FileInputStream and ObjectInputStream but nothing works. This is my current method:

```
public List<Feed> loadSubscribedFeeds(File feedsFile) {
    Scanner s = null;
    try {
        s = new Scanner(feedsFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
           List<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Feed> listFeed = new ArrayList<>();
            
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                listString.add(s.nextLine());
            }
            
            for(String f : listString) {
                listFeed.add(new Feed(f));
            }
            return listFeed;
}
```

here is also the Feed class:

```java
public class Feed implements Serializable, Comparable<Feed> {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String publishedDateString;
    private List<Entry> entries;
    
    
    public Feed(String url) {
        super();
        this.url = url;
        this.entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        this.title = "";
        this.description = "";
        this.publishedDateString = "";
    }
    
    /**
     * Creates an instance of a Feed and transfers the feed
     * data form a SyndFeed object to the new instance.
     * @param url The URL string of this feed
     * @param sourceFeed The SyndFeed object holding the data for this feed instance
     */
    public Feed(String url, SyndFeed sourceFeed) {
        this(url);
        setTitle(sourceFeed.getTitle());
        setDescription(sourceFeed.getDescription());
        
        if (sourceFeed.getPublishedDate() != null)
            setPublishedDateString(FeaderUtils.DATE_FORMAT.format(sourceFeed.getPublishedDate()));

        
        for (SyndEntry entryTemp : sourceFeed.getEntries()) {
            Entry entry = new Entry(entryTemp.getTitle());
            entry.setContent(entryTemp.getDescription().getValue());
            entry.setLinkUrl(entryTemp.getLink());
            entry.setParentFeedTitle(getTitle());
            if (entryTemp.getPublishedDate() != null) {
                entry.setPublishedDateString(FeaderUtils.DATE_FORMAT.format(entryTemp.getPublishedDate()));
            }
            addEntry(entry);
        }
    }
    
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title != null ? title : "";
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description != null ? description : "";
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setPublishedDateString(String publishedDateString) {
        this.publishedDateString = publishedDateString != null ? publishedDateString : "";
    }

    public String getPublishedDateString() {
        return publishedDateString;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns a short string containing a combination of meta data for this feed
     * @return info string
     */
    public String getShortFeedInfo() {
        return getTitle() + " [" +
                getEntriesCount() + " entries]: " + 
                getDescription() +
                (getPublishedDateString() != null && getPublishedDateString().length() > 0
                    ? " (updated " + getPublishedDateString() + ")"
                    : "");
    }
    
    public void addEntry(Entry entry) {
        if (entry != null) entries.add(entry);
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }
    
    public int getEntriesCount() {
        return entries.size();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Feed)
            && ((Feed)obj).getUrl().equals(url);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return url.hashCode();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Feed o) {
        return getPublishedDateString().compareTo(o.getPublishedDateString());
    }
    
}
```

Maybe someone out there will be able to help me or guide me in the correct direction.
Thanks already in advance.

Comment: Since Feed implements Serializable, you should not be trying to write your Feed objects as text.  Instead of FileWriter and Scanner, use [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html).writeObject and [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).readObject.

Comment: I changed the saveSubscribedFeeds method like this: `public void saveSubscribedFeeds(List<Feed> feeds, File feedsFile) {
  
  String tmp = feeds.toString();
     PrintWriter pw = null;
  try {
   pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(feedsFile));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
     pw.write(tmp);
     pw.close();
  
  
 }`        I do not know if it is any good but it passes the JUnit Test

Comment: Please clarify what part is not working, is the method that reads the file or the method that writes into the file that is not working. Also, what error do you get? what is the current result?